# Performance: Should I avoid constructor delegation?

Tags: java, performance, constructor

I was wondering if there is **any performance difference between running a constructor from within a constructor (*aka. constructor delegation*) and not**.

Please don't interpret this question as me supporting redundancy, like copying long constructors for a performance boost. I understand that in most cases, calling a constructor within a constructor is desirable for many reasons other than performance. (Readability, for example)

As an example, this is a `Vector3D` class that I've recently created:

```
public class Vector3D {

    public final int x, y, z;

    public Vector3D() {
        this(0, 0, 0);
    }

    public Vector3D(int x, int y, int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

Will I benefit from not calling `this(0, 0, 0)` and simply setting the variables myself like this?

```
public class Vector3D {

    public final int x, y, z;

    public Vector3D() {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
        this.z = 0;
    }

    public Vector3D(int x, int y, int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if there is a difference, you won't be able to notice it.

Comment: There is no performance impact; you just have an overloaded version...and if so, it would be irrelevant (for this case). You can try and do a benchmark on this by yourself

Comment: All methods called from constructors, should be final (according to PMD)...

Comment: @xerx593 or private. But a constructor cannot be overriden, it does not apply

Comment: @DIci: http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/rules/design.html#ConstructorCallsOverridableMethod ... and since when/why can't constructors be overwritten? (the "default constructor" can even be overwritten from `private` to `public`)

Comment: @xerx593 When you extend a class and define a constructor with the same signature as a constructor of the parent class, one of the constructors of the parent **must** be called at the very beginning of the new constructor. Then, it is not overriden. With overriding, you potentially replace 100% of the code, this is not the case here and this would make no point since it could break the inheritance of certain properties of behaviours. I know about passing the default constructor to `private`, but that is still not overriding since you can call it into the class, and itself calls `Object()`

Comment: @xerx593 try using `@Override` above a constructor, you'll see. You can also take a look at that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643362/overriding-constructors

Comment: If you are worried about constructor delegation overhead, chances are you are instantiating many objects in a short period of time. Take a look at [object pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) if you haven't done so already.

Comment: @xerx593, the rules for avoiding non-final helper methods called from constructors don't apply to the constructors themselves because you cannot override a constructor.  [Besides, you're confusing overriding with overloading.](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/constructor-overloading/)  AS AN ASIDE, if at all possible, helper methods ***even if declared final/private*** should be avoided if you can all help it.  Sooner or later a junior engineer will be a little too tempted to change that and override it in a subclass that he just "can't get to work any other way".

Comment: Using a mutable reference type to represent a value concept like a vector is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @CodesInChaos In a real example, `Vector3D` is immutable (all members are `private final`), but I figured that in this short example, making the members public would make more sense as there's no other way to access those members. I've made them `final` in an edit for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Main.java**

```
package pokus1;

public class Main {

    public int m_a;
    public int m_b;

    public Main(int a, int b) {

        m_a = a;
        m_b = b;

    }

    public Main() {
        this(0,0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main main = new Main();

    }

}
```

**Javap output (javap -v Main.class) for pokus1.Main():**

Do you see the `invokespecial` instruction on the offset `3`? This is the call to `pokus1.Main(int a,int b)`. So fundamentaly yes, it is more effective to not call the second constructor. But there are many optimizations in current JVM implementations, like method inlining, just-in-time compilation etc., so I think you doesn't need to think about it, otherwise you can think about every java call, if it is necessary.

```
public pokus1.Main();
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=3, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0       
         1: iconst_0      
         2: iconst_0      
         3: invokespecial #24                 // Method "<init>":(II)V
         6: return        
      LineNumberTable:
        line 16: 0
        line 17: 6
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
               0       7     0  this   Lpokus1/Main;
```

Comment: Surprised that this was not inlined ! Is this the Oracle JDK ?

Comment: Dici: it is compiled with Eclipse compiler. But it can be inlined at runtime, so it is ok.

Comment: I don't know... this could be done statically so why doing it at runtime ?

Comment: @Dici: because the JVM is very good in that. If you have short time running program, it doesn't matter if you inline few instructions. If your program will run for a long time, JVM will take care of it.

Comment: @Dici the javac compiler does not inline anything - inlining is performed by the JVM.

Answer (score 10):

You will never benefit from duplicating code. This is premature optimization. A method call costs nothing, unless you perform it very often in a short while. In this case, it is acceptable to inline the code if it is not used in too many places of the system, but that is not your case.

Imagine that one day you add another feature to your class. If you inlined the code, you will have to update two constructors instead of a single one. All the bits of code which logic is related should be related in code (basically calling the same nethods/using the same classes). That's how you build reusable code.

Don't overthink about performance, first think about design, clarity and reusability. The parts of your system that really need to be performant are algorithmic ones, this should not impact the design.

Comment: I would understand if you have a long constructor and copying it would be redundant, but for a `Vector3D`? This is a real class, and realistically there's no harm in picking three lines over one. In this case, doing it one way is just as easy as doing it the other. The question would then be: which way do I do it?

Comment: Because code is for humans, and has to be readable. You don't know what happens to your code when it gets compiled, but my guess is that it will compile into separate constructors however you write it. There is a syntax for calling other constructors of the same class, trust the language creators and use it, they must have thought about it.

Comment: ..unless "someone" comes and overwrites his `int, int, int` constructor.

Comment: @xerx593 Then this "someone" should come up with a good reason and find an alternative. What's the problem with this ? Should we not write methods just because another member of the team will potentially remove it in a refactoring ?

Comment: Agree with Dici here. The whole point is that you want the same code called, just with a set of default arguments. If the 3 arg version changes, the no arg version should change with it. This is easier if the no arg simply calls the 3 arg. Additionally, if you're in a situation where the performance difference of this kind of operation actually matters, you should be writing code that compiles to native. The gains of eliminating the VM altogether would be much larger.

Comment: *A method call costs nothing, unless you perform it very often in a short while* ==> that statement is very misleading - it's actually the opposite: if a method is called often it will be inlined by the JIT...

Comment: @assylias I meant that the individual cost of a method is virtually nothing if it is not call very often. The JIT might inline a method called often, but the JIT has its own cost, and what about a method which might be called very often in some burst periods but not always ? Personnaly, I would never rely on the JIT to optimize my code unless I have a deep knowledge of it.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, there is no difference at all, because [the just in time compiler inlines short methods](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/Inlining).

Moreover, even if the code was not inlined, the overhead caused by the two branch instructions in machine code is unlikely to materially affect the runtime of the entire program, unless the program spends most of its time working with these vectors.

Comment: I thought that the JIT leaves constructors specifically alone from inline op.  No?